# How to Make Advanced Navigation for Audiences in Communities?

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder, navigation, audience

I have a complex use case that involves audiences and navigation menu options but I don't know how to solve this puzzle using standard functionality.

My company is building a community that will have many community users, and these users will come from many Accounts, for example  500 Accounts.

We will offer (Eg) 7 services (or more) in this community, and each service has a navigation option in the navigation bar of the community (so each service is a page), for example

Services: A, B, C, D, E, F, G

We would like to have a behaviour in which users of one particular Account has access to only some of that services and no more. For example

**Universal Containers' users will have access to A and B only**

**Thomson Real State's users will have access to B,  C and D only**

**Bauer Stores' users will have access to A, C, E, and F only**

My goal is to give to the users access to the services that their Accounts are allowed and no others. I can create an audience for each account, but that would be a huge work because we have around 500 accounts, so I was wondering:

Can I show two audiences to the same user? for example, **if I define that A, B, C, D, E, F, G are audiences**, can I assign audience A to Universal Containers and Bauer Stores users? without having to create an audience, and one navigation menu, to each Account?

Thanks very much for having the time to read my long question, any advice will be very appreciated. Thanks a lot

**PD:** If this isn't possible and I have to add an audience for every Account, is there a way to replace at all the navigation menu with an LWC? thanks again.

Comment: Have you considered [Custom Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5) and [Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_custom_perms.htm&type=5)?  It's a lot of work to assign the users, but you can create audiences based on Custom Permissions.

Comment: @DavidCheng Hi David, yes I've considered the permissions as well but the problem is that apparently the navigation options from one navigation menu can't be joint with other options from other menu. So if a user should see the option A that is assigned to audience A but also the option B that is for audience B, he will only see either A or B but not both, because a user can only see things of one audience and not two or more audiences at the same time (in the navigation bar) so that's my puzzle, but thank you very much for your comment, I'll check

Comment: @Emmanuel_M Have you solved this problem? If yes, what is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom checkbox field for each service on the Account object (e.g. `Service A`, `Service B`, etc). Then create an Audience that shows the service based on the checkboxes. So service A pages will have the following audience:
[image: Service A Audience]
If your services are represented by pages, if you set the audience on the page, it will affect the visibility in the menu. Those who will have on the Account field `Service A` set to `false` won't see the menu item. And you don't need to create the Audience for each account but only for each service.

Hope it makes sense.